# Everything says Applocker is supposed to work: Why doesn't it?

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, applocker

I've setup a basic group policy consisting of the default Applocker rules. Per Microsoft's [technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460955.aspx) on the subject, any files not explicitly allowed to run by the policy are *supposed* to be blocked from running. After deploying this policy and verifying it was being applied to the correct user using `gpresult`, I was still able to download and run an exe from the internet, an exe that was saved to the user profile's temp folder. It was at that point I did more googling, and saw that the App Identity service had to be running, and it wasn't: So, like any good admin, I started it, set it to automatic, and rebooted just in case. The policy still didn't work after restarting. Below is a screenshot of the current policy.

[image]

I added the deny rules explicitly because the default rules weren't working. I correctly applied the policy to the machine and verified that the rules are enforced (it says so in the screenshot). I used the `Test-AppLockerPolicy` cmdlet to verify that the rule is should be blocking the EXEs and MSIs from running, but it doesn't. Open to most suggestions, no matter how ludicrous they may sound.

**Update**

Forgot to add that I checked the event log for AppLocker during this whole fiasco, and it was blank. Not a single entry the entire time.

Comment: Look in the event log under `Applications and Services Logs` -> `Microsoft` -> `Windows` -> `AppLocker`. In those logs you should see allowed/denied message, and also "The AppLocker policy was applied successfully to this computer.".

Comment: Also, you can set your Group Policy that contains your AppLocker rules to also start the Application Identity service.

Comment: @longneck you are right 100%: I forgot to add that I checked that log, and it was blank! And yes, eventually if I get this policy working right I will add that service to start automatically via the same gpo for consistency.

Comment: There are separate rules for "Windows Installer Rules". I don't know if that's relevant to your EXE but it's worth a look. If you drop a copy of an installed program's EXE (winword.exe, etc.) into a folder that's not permitted in your Executable Rules, is the user able to execute it?

Comment: @joeqwerty by 'Windows Installer Rules' are you referring to MSI files? That would be *horrible* if MS differentiated between 'Installed Program' EXEs and 'Windows Installer' EXEs, hopefully it's just extension based.

Comment: I'm saying I don't know how it handles that and that would be something I would test. I'm using AppLocker rules and haven't experienced the issue you're having, so it bears some additional investigation.

Comment: @joeqwerty I see, yeah it's up there in the screenshot, with the same rules (Allow from Windows\Installer and deny everything else), from their documentation it only applies to MSIs. thnx for the info though.

Comment: Is the user a local Admin? Is the machine Windows 7 Pro?

Comment: @joeqwerty Great questions, I *double checked* just now and the user is not an admin (that would be pretty embarrassing considering it's supposed to be a restricted account per production GPOs right now...), and it's indeed Windows 7 Enterprise.

Comment: How are you defining your deny path rule? Have you possibly forgot to add wildcard to the path *?

Comment: @FannarLevy It's in the screenshot, deny <user> from running exe's under the user profile folder. You think I need an asterisk somewhere?At the end of the path? I'd have to go back and look at how it's defined, but what boggles me is that the test-applocker cmdlet *confirms* it's supposed to be blocked, so the path has to be correct, right?

Comment: If the rules are correctly defined and "Application Identity" service is running then AppLocker should block.

Comment: First make sure you meet requirements, ex. Windows 10 Pro is not supported: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/applocker/requirements-to-use-applocker

Answer (score 4):

If your path block was not defined correctly then that would explain you situation.

For example if you were to use the %userprofile% environment variable. There are only a subset of the environment variables available through GPO/AppLocker and that's not one of them.

I have had success with the following path rule:

```
%osdrive%\users\*
```

Comment: Seconded here. I ran into the exact same issue with using the %userprofile% EV where it would not work. But switching over to the %osdrive%\users\* did the trick.

Comment: Switched jobs, for some reason I didn't see this answer before I left (July '14), I would have definitely tried it, it sounds like the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread but I came across it when implementing AppLocker on our own network.

AppLocker requires the use of the Application Identity service, which is set to Manual on a default install of Win7/Server 2008 R2.  You must set the Application Identity service to Automatic startup or the rules will not be enforced.  You can do this with the Group Policy object where AppLocker rules are defined.

Comment: Sup Wes! Yeah I saw that too, set it to auto with no avail, hope this thread helped you though

Comment: It did :-) It works fine w/ Win7. Win10 is another story. Can't even change the startup type of the service. Was going to post another question for that. I came across your thread while looking for help w/ AppLocker and ClickOnce applications.